# How to extract such a compressed file?

Tags: windows, compression, zip, tar, gzip

I have been asked to extract a **ZIP** file having in it 3 **tar** files and each tar file contains around 3000 **gz** files.

I had to extract the main **ZIP** file first then extract the **tar** files second then extract the **gz** files which took a time for me.

Is there a way to extract such file with one click?
I am using Windows and probably the file was compressed using a linux

Comment: What program are you using for 'unzipping'? Have you tried 7-zip?

Comment: in fact the problem here is how to extract thousands of archived packages at the same time - which might take a lot of time.  i imagine there are no parts of archives involved, but just simple archived folders/files. i doubt there is any solution which may shorten the necessary time for extracting so many archived files, but as far as 'one clicking' is concerned, select all and right-click 'extract here' may be the closest. 7-zip will act as a file manager/browser when opening the archive, it would navigate down to  the last level of the archives where such commands could be issued

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a "one-click" solution, but 7-Zip (http://www.7-zip.org/) is always my go-to applicaion in Windows for extracting archives. It supports all the formates you lised in your question.

A quick search for "7-zip recursive extract" led me straight to this answer here:
https://superuser.com/a/248349/201432. If you feel confident enough with command-line scripting, you might be able to apply that answer to your archive.

Answer (score 0):

See this http://www.dbforums.com/unix-shell-scripts/1619154-how-unzip-files-recursively.html

Custom script to unzip recursively